# jQuery file upload not firing validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, file-upload

I am using the jQuery file upload api to upload a document and some text on a form.

I was quite surprised that it even posted the fields on the form as it doesn't require that I even enclose the fields in a form in my page. I don't get how it works.

But it does, well... except the validation on my page doesn't fire. I can imagine this will be because of the lack of the form on the page.

Can anyone please give me some insight into what jquery is doing when I apply the fileupload functionality to the file input field and how this is possibly getting the form fields?

Here is the code in case you need to know exactly what I am doing.

```
inputField.fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: myUrl,
    replaceFileInput: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        // do stuff

    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        //do stuff
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        //do stuff
    }
})
```

Thanks

Edit:

As requested

- jQuery File Upload Plugin 5.40.0
- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
  *
- Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
- https://blueimp.net
  *
- Licensed under the MIT license:
- http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT

Edit:

Had a look in the linked code and think I (almost) get what's going on now... though I still have a question.

It appears the code is getting the forms using window.FormData which I presume gets the form fields on the page. Therefore it isn't submitting it in a conventional sense at all.

I guess I just need to add a form and then wrap the call in a form.valid() style check. But where would I put this check? Not of these api functions will be appropriate.

Comment: Please link the plugins you are using. That is not a core jQuery method

Comment: If this question is also about the jQuery Validate plugin, then where is the code relating to the validation?  So much is missing here.  Please follow this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I understand the need for giving clear examples but the validation is simply a requiredattribute against a string field/input box on a viewmodel. Nothing to show really?!